# I assign a pointer and it nulls itself out

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, scope, variable-assignment

So I have a constructor for an object, that on creation sets a few values and then places itself at the end of a linked list.

The problem I'm having is that when it assigns the address of the new object to the head or tail of the list, it assigns, leaves the constructor and for some reason the head and tail both get reset to 0.

```
Object Object1("OddJob", 2, 2, 9);
```

calls constructor

```
Object::Object(string label, float x, float y, float z)
{
  x_ = x;
  y_ = y;
  z_ = z;
  if(label == "")
  {
    label = "Object";
  }
  label_ = label;
  if(headObject == 0)
  {
    headObject = this;
    tailObject = this;
  }
  else
  {
    tailObject->next = this;
    tailObject = this;
  }
  next = 0;
}
```

Edit: headObject and tailObject are globals declared in a .h file. They are declared as:

```
static Object * headObject;
static Object * tailObject;
```

Comment: Where do `headObject` and `tailObject` come from?

Comment: They are globals declared in a .h file. They are created as static Object * headObject and static Object * tailObject

Comment: If they're declared in a .h file, are the defined in a single .cpp file somewhere?  If not, you might be getting an instance per compilation unit...

Comment: They're declared as `static`. This means each `.cpp` file gets its own copy of them.

Comment: defined meaning used? I am using them in my main.cpp for right now, just setting them to 0 before any of the constructors are called

Comment: Crud, okay, let me see what happens when I drop the static... Hopefully this works

Comment: Nope, without the static I'm getting linker errors...

Comment: @JoelShook I explain that in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `static` on a global object causes it to have internal linkage. This means that each translation unit that includes your header will have its *own* version of `headObject` and `tailObject`.

Instead, you should declare them as `extern` in the header file:

```
extern Object * headObject;
extern Object * tailObject;
```

Then in a single translation unit (typically the `.cpp` corresponding to that `.h`), you should give the definitions as:

```
Object * headObject;
Object * tailObject;
```

You can't just define them like this in the header file, otherwise you'll break the one definition rule when you include the header in multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Either declare the headObject and tailObject as static members of the Object class.

```
class Object
{
    static Object* headObject;
    static Object* tailObject;
    // Rest of class.
}
```

Not forgetting to define them in the Object.cpp as follows:

```
Object* Object::headObject = nullptr;
Object* Object::tailObject = nullptr;
```

Or define them as "extern" in the header:

```
extern Object* headObject;
extern Object* tailObject;
```

and then define them in the Object.cpp:

```
Object* headObject = nullptr;
Object* tailObject = nullptr;
```

Otherwise you are essentially defining them in every cpp file that includes the .h.  The static simply says to each of those files that they have their own version of those variables that are distinct from each other.  Thus headObject in main.cpp is not the same as headObject in Object.cpp.  Do not confuse class statics and non class statics.  The linker error you see without the static is explaining what the problem is.  If you get such a link error look it up and try and learn WHY you are getting it otherwise you will make hard to track down errors like you are seeing.